# How to add some more parameter in swagger api documentation

Tags: api, swagger

I am creating API documentation using swagger. I have created the API. In one api, I have audio. This API is returning audio file name. Now I want to add audio path in the documentation so that API user can play the audio. 
Like, I am returning a audio file named `song.mp3`. To play this audio API user need full path of this file. like `example.com/audio/song.mp3`. Here `example.com` is the site name. and `audio` is the folder name where `song.mp3` is stored.

This is how I have created API.

```
<?php
/**
@SWG\Post(
    path="/api/audios",
    tags={"audios"},
    summary="returns all audios",
    description="This resource represents an individual user in the system.
    Each user is identified by a numeric",
    resourcepath = "store",
    @SWG\Parameter(
        name="Authorization",
        in="header",
        description="Token to access Audio File",
        required=true,
        type="string",
        default="Bearer TOKEN",
        description="Authorization"
    ),
    @SWG\Response(
        response="200",
        description="Successful operation",
    ),
    @SWG\Response(
        response=400,
        description="Invalid Code | Code not in request"
    ),
    @SWG\Response(
        response=401,
        description="Invalid token | Header Token is missing"
    ),
)

@SWG\Post(
    path="/api/audios/{audioId}",
    tags={"audios"},
    summary="returns single audio",
    @SWG\Parameter(
        name="Authorization",
        in="header",
        description="Token to access Audio File",
        required=true,
        type="string",
        default="Bearer TOKEN",
        description="Authorization"
    ),
    @SWG\Parameter(
        name="audioId",
        in="path",
        description="Id of Audio File",
        required=true,
        type="string",
        default="123"
    ),
    @SWG\Response(
        response="200",
        description="Successful operation",
    ),
    @SWG\Response(
        response=404,
        description="Audio not found"
    ),
    @SWG\Response(
        response=401,
        description="Invalid token | Header Token is missing"
    )
)
*/
```

I just need to add `example.com/audio` in a proper place so that API user can understand this audio is stored in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it in the response with status code 200. See more on this in [the Swagger-PHP docs](http://zircote.com/swagger-php/Getting-started.html#write-annotations) and in [the main Swagger docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/).